# Matrial-UI <Autocomplete /> search by multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So i've started learning Material UI and i have a question.

We have an object

```
const top100Films = [
  { label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { label: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 }, 

  * ...More items *
]
```

Right now if i set `getOptionLabel = {option => option.label}` in my Autocomplete it will only search by matching label(title) so if i enter a year i.e "1994" it won't show "The Shawshank Redemption" in my search results, and if i set it to `option.year` it will only search by year and any input but year will be invalid.

Here's my question: Is there a way to set it so i can search both by title or by year.

Solution:

```
<Autocomplete
  ...
  filterOptions={(options, { inputValue }) => options.filter(item => item.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue) || item.year.toString().includes(inputValue) )}
/>
```

Comment: https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MUI Autocomplete API has `filterOptions` ([docs here](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/)) prop where you can set custom filtering.

I would implement it something like:

```
<Autocomplete
  ...
  filterOptions={(options, { inputValue }) => options.filter(item => item.label.includes(inputValue) || item.year.toString.includes(inputValue) )}
/>
```

Comment: With small adjustments your suggestion works great ! Thank you ! Only needed to add conversion to lower case for titles.

Comment: Also added .toLowerCase() to both sides so that the search isn't case sensitive